# Помогите исправить ошибку в создании продукта

Tags: postgresql, typescript, prisma

при работе с призмой (prisma) у меня возникает ошибка, в которой я бы хотел разобраться и исправить ее.

Я прописал сидер, в котором и создается мой продукт с рандомно генерируемыми полями:

```js
import { PrismaClient, Product } from '@prisma/client';
import * as dotenv from '/4/shoes-store/node_modules/dotenv';
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
//import { generateSlug } from 'src/utils/generate-slug';
//import { randomInt } from 'crypto';
dotenv.config();
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const createProducts = async (quantity: number) => {
    const products: Product[] = []


    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        const productName = faker.commerce.productName()
        const typeName = faker.commerce.department()

        const product = await prisma.product.create({
            data: {
                name: productName,
                slug: faker.helpers.slugify(productName),
                description: faker.commerce.productDescription(),
                price: +faker.commerce.price(100, 400),
                images: Array.from({
                    length: faker.datatype.number({ min: 3, max: 5 })
                }).map(() =>
                    faker.image.imageUrl()
                ),
                type: {
                    create: {
                        name: typeName,
                        slug: faker.helpers.slugify(typeName),

                    }
                },
                reviews: {
                    create: [
                        {
                            rating: faker.datatype.number({ min: 3, max: 5 }),
                            text: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                            user: {
                                connect: {
                                    id: 2
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            rating: faker.datatype.number({ min: 3, max: 5 }),
                            text: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                            user: {
                                connect: {
                                    id: 3
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
        products.push(product)
    }


    console.log(`Created ${products.length} products :D`)

}




async function main() {
    console.log('Start seeding...')

    await createProducts(10)
}

main()
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .finally(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect
    })
```

Вот сама ошибка. Пишет, что я нарушаю ограничение на ненулевость кода бренда.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я ведь прописал `| null` в `index.d.ts`.

```js
/**
 * Model Product
 * 
 */
export type Product = {
  id: number
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
  name: string
  slug: string
  description: string
  price: Prisma.Decimal
  images: string[]
  typeId: number
  brandId: number | null //вроде как не нулевой
  userId: number | null
}
```

Помогите исправить ошибку, пожалуйста.

Comment: судя по сообщению об ошибку, в БД у вас есть колонка brand_id и она NOT NULL, а при создании вы не посылаете данные в brandId

Comment: @nörbörnën имеете ввиду, мне нужно еще прописать `brand: {create: {name: brandName}`
так?

Comment: я не знаю что нужно прописать, просто объясняю суть проблемы.

Comment: @nörbörnën принял, спасибо, ща буду пробовать исправить..

Comment: помощь все равно нужна, товарищи ._.